# signature and/or required key >missing - tainting kernel CrystalHD

Tags: kernel

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit with Gnome on my plastic 2007 MacBook. The laptop is still going strong, but I wanted to reduce the load on my CPU when dealing with video files. To do this, I installed a CrystalHD BCM70015 into the WiFi slot and am running a USB WiFi adaptor. CrystalHD is a video acceleration card, not a video card. After installation of the crystalhd drivers I wanted to see if it was working, and this the output. Does this mean it's not working? Did the module verification fail due to wrong headers?

```
cycomiko@TuxBook:~$ dmesg | grep crystalhd
[    9.916733] crystalhd: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    9.917127] Loading crystalhd v3.10.0
[    9.917153] crystalhd 0000:02:00.0: Starting Device:0x1615
[    9.918075] crystalhd 0000:02:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
```

Comment: My guess is that you need to disable secure boot, but I am not sure. Later it appears the module loaded, is the device working ?

Comment: possibly duplicate of this question [module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975377/kvm-module-verification-failed-signature-and-or-required-key-missing-taintin)